# AWS SSM lookup using arns in ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-ssm

I am getting only ssm resource arns, so I need to get a secret using arns

my ansible example arn looks like below

ARN: which is exists, checked via console

```
arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:1234578909:secret:test/myuser/pass1
```

I tried below ansible code but did not work.

```
 debug: msg="{{ lookup('aws_ssm', 'arn:aws:ssm:us-west-2:1234578909:secret:test/myuser/pass1  ) }}"
```

returing empty ..

Comment: You got any work around?